# Http does not set timeout, why the program will get stuck

Tags: java, http

The background timer task, after running for a period of time, found that it stopped, tracked the next log, found that the program stuck in the following line of code

> HttpResponse response = HttpUtils.doGet(host, path, method, headers, querys);

As you can see in the stack information, the thread is always running.

```
"startQuertz_Worker-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb24523f800 nid=0x788f runnable [0x00007fb25d85f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)

locked <0x000000078438d710> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
locked <0x000000078438d7c0> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at com.redhorse.cron.util.HttpUtils.doGet(HttpUtils.java:57)
at com.redhorse.cron.util.AliExchangeUtil.getExchangeInfo(AliExchangeUtil.java:31)
at com.redhorse.cron.job.ExchangeRateJob.update(ExchangeRateJob.java:30)
at com.redhorse.cron.job.ExchangeRateJob.handleJob(ExchangeRateJob.java:79)
at com.redhorse.cron.job.BaseJob.doJob(BaseJob.java:18)
at com.redhorse.cron.QuartzCronJobs.updateExchangeRateViaBank(QuartzCronJobs.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:257)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
locked <0x0000000782aa3800> (a java.lang.Object)
Locked ownable synchronizers:

None
```

Here is the http tool code, I think it is not set in the code timeout

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpUtils {

    /**
     * get
     *
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doGet(String host, String path, String method,
                                     Map<String, String> headers,
                                     Map<String, String> querys)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * post form
     *
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @param bodys
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doPost(String host, String path, String method,
                                      Map<String, String> headers,
                                      Map<String, String> querys,
                                      Map<String, String> bodys)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        if (bodys != null) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            for (String key : bodys.keySet()) {
                nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, bodys.get(key)));
            }
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList, "utf-8");
            formEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * Post String
     *
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @param body
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doPost(String host, String path, String method,
                                      Map<String, String> headers,
                                      Map<String, String> querys,
                                      String body)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(body)) {
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "utf-8"));
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * Post stream
     *
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @param body
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doPost(String host, String path, String method,
                                      Map<String, String> headers,
                                      Map<String, String> querys,
                                      byte[] body)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        if (body != null) {
            request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(body));
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * Put String
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @param body
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doPut(String host, String path, String method,
                                     Map<String, String> headers,
                                     Map<String, String> querys,
                                     String body)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpPut request = new HttpPut(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(body)) {
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "utf-8"));
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * Put stream
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @param body
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doPut(String host, String path, String method,
                                     Map<String, String> headers,
                                     Map<String, String> querys,
                                     byte[] body)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpPut request = new HttpPut(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        if (body != null) {
            request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(body));
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    /**
     * Delete
     *
     * @param host
     * @param path
     * @param method
     * @param headers
     * @param querys
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static HttpResponse doDelete(String host, String path, String method,
                                        Map<String, String> headers,
                                        Map<String, String> querys)
            throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(host);

        HttpDelete request = new HttpDelete(buildUrl(host, path, querys));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    private static String buildUrl(String host, String path, Map<String, String> querys) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder sbUrl = new StringBuilder();
        sbUrl.append(host);
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(path)) {
            sbUrl.append(path);
        }
        if (null != querys) {
            StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> query : querys.entrySet()) {
                if (0 < sbQuery.length()) {
                    sbQuery.append("&");
                }
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(query.getKey()) && !StringUtils.isBlank(query.getValue())) {
                    sbQuery.append(query.getValue());
                }
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(query.getKey())) {
                    sbQuery.append(query.getKey());
                    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(query.getValue())) {
                        sbQuery.append("=");
                        sbQuery.append(URLEncoder.encode(query.getValue(), "utf-8"));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (0 < sbQuery.length()) {
                sbUrl.append("?").append(sbQuery);
            }
        }

        return sbUrl.toString();
    }

    private static HttpClient wrapClient(String host) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if (host.startsWith("https://")) {
            sslClient(httpClient);
        }

        return httpClient;
    }

    private static void sslClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String str) {

                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String str) {

                }
            };
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = httpClient.getConnectionManager();
            SchemeRegistry registry = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, ssf));
        } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question? And/or have you tried setting the connection and/or read timeouts?

Comment: @BrianAgnew，Question: Why is HTTP stuck in the request interface? I am not sure if it is related to timeout, and this general problem is hard to reproduce in the formal environment.I am not sure if I added a timeout, it will avoid such a problem!

Comment: As long as you don't set a timeout, the HttpConnection waits indefinitely for a response. See https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html for how to set such a timeout.

Comment: @Sascha，Ok, I am looking at the documentation, thank you very much.